Sci-Fi time from a child can be given to add time to their parent
Sci-Fi show:
Time from a child can be given to add time to their parent.
Everyone knows how much time they have from a watch received at birth.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can time only be given from a child to their parent, or can any two people exchange time?  Do people actually have a physical wrist- or pocket watch, or is it a tattoo on their wrist?  When and where did you see this?  Can people earn more time?

Is it "In Time" with Justin Timberlake? No time to post a proper answer. (Though it's a movie, not a show)

@AndresF. There are two movies I can think of off the top of my head that have lifetimers and use time as currency: In Time and The Price of Life (which I've IDed a couple of times before).  The questions I asked were intended to help distinguish.

Also sounds like In Time (2011).
From Wikipedia:

In Time is a 2011 American science fiction action film [...] Justin Timberlake and Amanda Seyfried star as inhabitants of a society that uses time from one's lifespan as its primary currency, with each individual possessing a clock on their arm that counts down how long they have to live.





It actually sounded more like In Time to me than The Price of Life because the wrist tattoo in the former is closer to a watch than the point-of-sale terminals used in the latter.

Is this The Price of Life (1987)...?
From Wikipedia:

The basic premise of the film is that a time account is physically linked to every infant at birth, with death automatic when the balance drops to zero. An elite upper-class is portrayed as living hundreds of years or more. The protagonist is given a certain amount of time as an infant, and as a young boy adds days and years to his time account by buying valuables from people and selling them to visiting tourists from the rich enclave. After his sister dies after gambling away her time, the protagonist (now a young man) sets out on a journey to the enclave of "the Old Ones" in order to save the life of his mother, who is (literally) running out of time. He gets there and meets a beautiful older woman who co-opts him into the immortal lifestyle.





One of the key features was that the boy character couldn't give his mother time. That's a key tenet of their society. That being said, he certainly tries to make it happen

He also doesn't have a clock on his wrist. They have a credit card and a reader.

The boy couldn't give time to his mother by default, but he could with permission from one of the Old Ones. And the card readers that everyone carries around with them double as speaking clocks, comparable to a pocket watch.

I don't disagree that some elements match OPs description if you squint hard enough

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt21308888/
This is Paradise, a German film released on Netflix in 2023.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Since there are two answers here already, you should provide a similar level of detail in your answer to demonstrate how good a match it is.

This seems like a very poor match based on the trailer. There doesn't seem to be any parent-child relationship, nor a clock showing their remaining life. Other than the general concept of transferring years of life between people, it's not a match at all.
